# Assign permission to user, not to role using Entrust in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 to develop an application and i'd like to assign roles and permissions to users using Zizaco/Entrust. For a better understanding let me give you an example:

I have 4 roles in my db: guest, user, admin, owner. The owner has full access on the administration panel and the main site, the admin has limited acces on the administration panel and full on the main site, users should have custom acces on the main site, and guests should have no access at all (stuck on the home page until they are given a user role).

The problem i'm facing is with the custom access to users. Having 4 main pages, users should ask for permissions to one or more of them. In the main page they can upload files, and do some other stuff too.

What i want to do is give them all the role of user, but for example, user A has permission to ONLY view Page 1, being unable to upload files or any of the other stuff, user B has permission to view Page 3 and Page 4, upload files only to Page 3, and do the other stuff to Page 4 except upload files.
I think you got the picture.

Can this be done with Entrust only, or should i make a new pivot table between Users and Permissions and work with it to accomplish what i need?

Thank you very much in advance,

Dragos

**Edit:**
What i previously thought about was giving them multiple roles such as "viewer-to-page-one","uploader-to-page-one","viewer-to-page-2" and so on, but then the permissions table will be totally useless in my db.

To conclude, what i want to accomplish is when a user with read-only permissions to Page 1 and Page 2 logs in, i want the following data in the session:

```
['id'->1,'name'->'user's name','email'->'users's email','role'->'user','permissions'->['view-page-1','view-page-2']]
```

So he can only view Page 1 and Page 2, but not upload files or anything else.

And when a user with view and upload files permissions to Page 1 logs in, i want:

```
['id'->2,'name'->'user's name','email'->'users's email','role'->'user','permissions'->['view-page-1','upload-to-page-1']]
```

So he can only view Page 1 and upload files to Page 1.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit late on answering this question, but this is just for anyone else who arrives on this page.

Well to be honest you are completely right about the permissions table being useless. If someone is building a site from scratch, he will tailor the system according to his needs. I really like entrust and the reason why entrust doesn't have this functionality is because assigning permissions directly to users is a bad design architecture. The only reason why the permissions table exist is just because of small size application. Cases where you have a single resource, and all the roles are actually using the same resource. In these cases instead of checking for each user, you can simply check for the permission. But in a practical medium/large application you would have individual controllers for each role.